# xaml - Create Resources with UI

Tags: xaml, resources

normally if i create a template for an ListView Item or something else, I'm not able to see the result until i start my application and fill the List with Items.

Something like that:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button>Complex DataTemplate</Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Well i want to see a preview of my ItemTemplate while I create it, but I do not know how...

Answer (score 0):

You can create design-time data to bind to so the list can fill with data in the designer. See [Displaying data in the designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh758320.aspx#displaying_data_in_the_designer) for how to set this up.